# RabbitMQ Consumer fails while receiving a MQTT message

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, pika

I'm trying to publish a MQTT message and receive the message with an AMQP consumer by using the RabbitMQ-MQTT plugin on Ubuntu14.04. I'm publishing the MQTT message with the Mosquitto-clients package. I enabled the MQTT plugin for RabbitMQ.

Now if I want to send a MQTT message, my AMQP consumer code throws an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "consume_topic.py", line 33, in <module>
channel.start_consuming()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 722, in start_consuming
self.connection.process_data_events()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 88, in process_data_events
if self._handle_read():
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 184, in _handle_read
super(BlockingConnection, self)._handle_read()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 308, in _handle_read
self._on_data_available(data)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 1134, in _on_data_available
consumed_count, frame_value = self._read_frame()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 1201, in _read_frame
return frame.decode_frame(self._frame_buffer)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/frame.py", line 254, in decode_frame
out = properties.decode(frame_data[12:])
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/spec.py", line 2479, in decode
(self.headers, offset) = data.decode_table(encoded, offset)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/data.py", line 106, in decode_table
value, offset = decode_value(encoded, offset)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/data.py", line 174, in decode_value
raise exceptions.InvalidFieldTypeException(kind)
pika.exceptions.InvalidFieldTypeException: b
```

My Pika (python) consumer code is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import sys

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.exchange_declare(exchange='logs',type='topic',durable=False)

result = channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
queue_name = result.method.queue

binding_keys = sys.argv[1:]
if not binding_keys:
    print >> sys.stderr, "Usage: %s [binding_key]..." % (sys.argv[0],)
    sys.exit(1)

for binding_key in binding_keys:
   channel.queue_bind(exchange='logs',
                      queue=queue_name,
                      routing_key=binding_key)

print ' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C'

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print " [x] %r:%r" % (method.routing_key, body,)

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue=queue_name,
                      no_ack=True)

channel.start_consuming()
```

My RabbitMQ configuration file is the following:

```
[{rabbit,        [{tcp_listeners,    [5672]}]},
 {rabbitmq_mqtt, [{default_user,     <<"guest">>},
                  {default_pass,     <<"guest">>},
                  {allow_anonymous,  true},
                  {vhost,            <<"/">>},
                  {exchange,         <<"logs">>},
                  {subscription_ttl, 1800000},
                  {prefetch,         10},
                  {ssl_listeners,    []},
                  %% Default MQTT with TLS port is 8883
                  %% {ssl_listeners,    [8883]}
                  {tcp_listeners,    [1883]},
                  {tcp_listen_options, [binary,
                                        {packet,    raw},
                                        {reuseaddr, true},
                                        {backlog,   128},
                                        {nodelay,   true}]}]}
].
```

The log file shows the following:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 14-Apr-2015::10:57:50 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.1174.0> (127.0.0.1:42447 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 14-Apr-2015::10:58:30 ===
accepting MQTT connection <0.1232.0> (127.0.0.1:53581 -> 127.0.0.1:1883)

=WARNING REPORT==== 14-Apr-2015::10:58:30 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.1174.0> (127.0.0.1:42447 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly

=INFO REPORT==== 14-Apr-2015::10:58:30 ===
closing MQTT connection <0.1232.0> (127.0.0.1:53581 -> 127.0.0.1:1883)
```

Can anybody please help me? I googled the "pika.exceptions.IvalidFieldTypeException" and found that I'm not using a correct "Field Type", how is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a bug in the specifications (decoder) for pika. I would recommend that you change library to something more frequently updated. As an example you could look at the author of pika's new library [RabbitPy](https://github.com/gmr/rabbitpy) or my very own pika inspired library [AMQP-Storm](https://github.com/eandersson/amqp-storm/tree/master/examples).

Although, it could also be that you are running a very old version of Pika. I found [this](https://github.com/pika/pika/commit/7e1b6fc93c79058a5ce4e7db62e1605021b139c3) commit from gmr that should have fixed your issue. You could try to upgrade to [pika 0.9.14](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pika).

Comment: Updated Pika and now it works just fine! I was still working with an old Pika version because the RabbitMQ tutorials suggested to work with Pika v0.9.8 Thank you very much!

Comment: Yea, there are a few new issues with the latest Pika version unfortunately. A lot of them will be fixed in 0.9.15.